# Apply class to each row in javascript Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table inside modal that has several hundreds items. Each item row is associated with particular bag. All bags are listed on a page and when user clicks **"Add Items"** modal opens up and shows all rows.

Now each row contain a class that correspond to its bag. I want to show only those rows that has same class as of that bag. I applied simple jQuery but that function only works on first page and rest of the pages shows all rows.

Is there any built in function provided by Datatables that could be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you have your datatable like this:

```js
var table = $("#myTable").dataTable({ 
   // ... skipped ...
});
```

You can edit its rows by selecting them with the `row()` function:

```js
table
     .row($(':not(.someBag)')
     .remove()
     .draw();
```

As you can see after selecting the rows we can remove them with `remove()` and the use `draw()` to reload the table from the cache.
This will delete also the rows on the other pages, not just the one you have rendered in front of you.

Comment: OK if I have to select rows that don't have particular class and hide it how could I do that. Sorry not very good with javascript.

Comment: @Epistemologist well you really need some way to identify the row. You should add a class to each row that you need to select when you generate your html table. After that it's going to be easy to select the rows.

Comment: OK thanks for your help let me check if this works and I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Epistemologist no problem, glad to be helpful :)

Comment: It actually should be `table.row($(':not(.someBag)').remove.draw()` if @Epistemologist wants to show only those rows with class `.someBag`.

Comment: Actually there is another problem now I have successfully hidden these rows but datatable does not register hidden rows and total number of rows are not affected.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com whops you're right, thanks for noticing.

Comment: @Epistemologist what do you mean with "does not register hidden rows and total number of rows are not affected"? I'm using that same code right now in one of my projects and the total nr of entries seems to be correct. Can you explain the new problem?

Comment: Before I explain let me ask you is there a solution to simply hide rows than remove them?

Comment: table.row($(':not(.someBag)').Visible=false; or you could just use jquery's hide()

Comment: @Epistemologist, there is a way to filter the table instead of removing the rows but you need to clarify details in your question as the implementation may depend on that. Also the title of your question is "Apply class to each row in javascript Datatables" which is a bit of misleading compared to what you want to do.

Comment: Gyrocode: Above answer solved my problem. I was thinking of it wrong way. But thanks for your input